# Is it posible count a column as empty and dont skip it with awk

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a text file that I got from a PDF file with tables. The table structure: run code to see structure

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>monday</th>
  <th>tuesday</th>
  <th>wednesday</th>
  <th>thursday</th>
  <th>friday</th>
 </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>XXX</td>
  <td>14:30</td>
  <td>14:30</td>
  <td>     </td>
  <td>14:30</td>
  <td>14:30</td>
  
  </tr>
  </table>
```

As you see Wednesday is empty and I need to insert the times to a database. And I have no idea how I can count the empty field as empty.

Comment: How do you know it's Wednesday and not another day? (And where are Sunday and Friday?)

Comment: its a example  how it can look like it diffrent from every name, is a schedule for a school

Comment: Now you've taken out the example data and say "run code" but there's no code.

Comment: haha sorry am new at this, its back now

Comment: right now I use cut to grab the time, but it doesn't feel right.
the file that has the time and names are not in line all the time

Comment: Ah! You need to use a tool that is intended for parsing (X)HTML! [Don't use the wrong tools.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/26428). For example, use [xpath](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/xpath.1p.html).

Comment: no its nothing to do with html. its a bash code that need to know where its a empty space so when the time is put in a database it will not go to the wring column wrong

Comment: The data you show looks an awful lot like an HTML table to me.

Comment: haha ya but html code above is just for how it looks like when the pdf file is converted to a txt file.

Comment: you know in bash when i typ "awk {'print $4'}" I want the time from wednesday but its empty. So I want the "script" to say "wednesday time empty". but insted for taking the wednesday time  "awk {'print $4'}" takes the thursday time

Comment: It's not helpful for people to see data which is not the data you're working with. If the HTML table above is "Point A" in your processing and the data that you had previously posted is "Point B" then there's no way to go from Point B to the desired result, but there is if you start at Point A and forget about B completely.

Comment: 5 days, four values. How do you know which one is missing? Maybe you have 2 tabs, spaces or other delimiters?

Comment: sorry but o cant post the real data beacuse of GDPR its a schedule for school